# Saving JPA @Enumerated value into the database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save @Enumerated value into the database:

```
@Entity
public class Macronutrient {

    public enum Group {
        CARBOHYDRATE, PROTEIN, FAT
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Group group;

    //getters and setters

}
```

I am sending PATCH request to modify existing Macronutrient:

```
PATCH /macronutrients
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Macronutrient",
    "group": "CARBOHYDRATE"
}
```

The code responsible for handling the update:

```
public Macronutrient patchMacronutrient(Macronutrient macronutrient) {
    ...
    if (Objects.nonNull(macronutrient.getGroup())) {
        existingMacronutrient.setGroup(macronutrient.getGroup());
    }
    ...
}
```

The response I am getting:
**ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"**

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        public.macronutrient 
    set
        
    group=?,
    name=? where
        id=?
```

If I DON'T set the `group` property on Macronutrient then it saved properly.
Please help!

Comment: Does the `group` column exist in the DB?

Comment: group is a reserved keyword in mysql, would suggest naming it nutrientGroup or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason could be that 'group' is a reserved word (think about "group by" expressions).
You may give a try to this: enclose the column name within backticks

```
@Column(name="`group`")
private Group group;
```

In JPA 2.0, the syntax is a bit different:

```
@Column(name="\"group\"")
```

and see it this works better.